# Switching on structure passed as constructor parameter in C++

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I have a config header file with static configuration used in class 'MyClass'.

In class_config.h

```cpp
typedef enum {
    SEQUENCE_1 = 5,
    SEQUENCE_2 = 8,
} Sequence;

typedef struct {
    int Position;
    Sequence FirstSequence;
    Sequence SecondSequence;   
} Map;

typedef struct {
    Map Mapping01;
    Map Mapping02;
} Config;

Config DefaultConfig {
    {
       1,
       SEQUENCE_1,
       SEQUENCE_2 
    },
    {
       2,
       SEQUENCE_2,
       SEQUENCE_2 
    },
};
```

In class.h

```cpp
Class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass(const Config &config);
private:
   void Foo(int position);
   const Config &internal_config;
}
```

In class.cpp

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass(const Config &config) : internal_config(config)
{ }

void MyClass:Foo(int position)
{
  switch(position)
  {
     case internal_config.Mapping01.Position : // error : "this" cannot be used in a constant expression
         // Get : internal_config.Mapping01.SEQUENCE_1
         break;
     default:
         break;
  }
}
```

In my method 'Foo' I'd like to find if 'position' is equal to *internal_config.Mapping01.Position* or *internal_config.Mapping02.Position* for example to return the corresponding sequence mapped with.
But I get the following error when compiling :  "this" cannot be used in a constant expression

I know that switch case requires const expression at building time but this is what I though I was doing. Using if else pattern instead of the switch case one is quite bothering me.

Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: The value of the member `internal_config` is only known at runtime after it has been initialized by the constructor call. Why is using if else bothering you?

Comment: You can ditch the `typedef`s. C++ is not C.

Comment: The case statements require integral value which must be known at compile-time.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number in my scenario I've more than 2 mappings, isn't switch case faster than if else statement ?

Comment: @Sté Isn't that the case in my example?

Comment: @LPo IMHO, _this_ cannot be evaluated at _compile time_, and the same apply to its properties.

Comment: @LPo maybe a _strategy pattern_ would fit here.

Comment: @LPo -- switch case isn't faster than `if ... else` if a switch isn't valid. <g> But in general, when there are only constants involved (so a switch would be valid), an `if .. else` ladder will often compile to the same code as a `switch` statement. Compilers are pretty smart!